# Creating a realistic Strum on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

So I have a guitar application that plays chords, like an autoharp. I have created the following UIView class to turn a swipe into a strum as the user's fingers swipe across the strings.

```
#import "swipetest.h"


@implementation swipetest

@synthesize eStringButton, aStringButton, dStringButton, gStringButton, bStringButton, ehStringButton;



- (void)viewDidLoad {
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(isolateStrums) toTarget:self withObject:nil]; }



- (void)isolateStrums {  

NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(touchesMoved) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];  
[pool release];  

}  
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
UIView *subview = [self hitTest:location withEvent:event];
if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
{



 if(CGRectContainsPoint(eStringButton.frame, location)) {
     [eStringButton setHighlighted:YES];
 [eStringButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:strumDelay target:self selector:@selector(ETimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    }

  else {

      [eStringButton setHighlighted:NO];


  }


  if(CGRectContainsPoint(ehStringButton.frame, location)) {
      [ehStringButton setHighlighted:YES];
      [ehStringButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

  }
  else {

      [ehStringButton setHighlighted:NO];

  }


if(CGRectContainsPoint(bStringButton.frame, location)) {
      [bStringButton setHighlighted:YES];
      [bStringButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

  }
else {

     [bStringButton setHighlighted:NO];


}

 if(CGRectContainsPoint(aStringButton.frame, location)) {
    [aStringButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [aStringButton setHighlighted:YES];

    }
else {

    [aStringButton setHighlighted:NO];


}


 if(CGRectContainsPoint(dStringButton.frame, location)) {
        [dStringButton setHighlighted:YES];

    [dStringButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    }
else {
    [dStringButton setHighlighted:NO];



}
     if(CGRectContainsPoint(gStringButton.frame, location)) {
       [gStringButton setHighlighted:YES];
        [gStringButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    }
    else {
        [gStringButton setHighlighted:NO];



    }




}       

}





- (void)dealloc {
[eStringButton release];
[aStringButton release];
[bStringButton release];
[gStringButton release];
[dStringButton release];
[ehStringButton release];



[super dealloc];
}



@end
```

The problem is that the view registers rapid fire "hits" even at normal strum speeds. How can I slow down the interface response? I cannot use any commands that pause the NSthread. Is there a way to disable the UIButton for a predetermined period of time after it receives the UIControlEventTouchDown message, say for 0.1 seconds? Should I create individual threads for each string and pause those threads? Right now it kind of works, but can easily turn into the "matrix" sounding stutter guitar. Not good.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to disable the UIButton
>   for a predetermined period of time
>   after it receives the
>   UIControlEventTouchDown message, say
>   for 0.1 seconds?

Sure - you can use an NSTimer to change the button's .userInteractionEnabled property. Just set it to 'NO' as soon as you detect your touch down, and fire a timer to set it back to 'YES' after a set number/fractions of seconds.